# How to iterate throgh XAttribute of XElement in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XElement structure:

```
XElement xmleElement=

<portal>
 <form patientid="72615" consentformid="430" appointmentid="386919"   actiontype="3">
   <signatures>
     <signature signatureid="858" encodedsignature="rkJggg==" />
   <signature signatureid="859" encodedsignature="" />
    </signatures>
  </form>
</portal>
```

Now I want to iterate through this elements each signature and get each encodedsignature XAttribute.
Basically want each portal/form/signatures/sugnature[encodedsignature] attribute using some foreach kind of iterator.
Any help will be highly appretiated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
var encodedSignatures = doc.Descendants("signature")
                           .Select(x => x.Attribute("encodedSignature").Value;
```

Or to be more explicit about the path:

```
var encodedSignatures = doc.Root
                           .Element("form")
                           .Element("signatures")
                           .Elements("signature")
                           .Select(x => x.Attribute("encodedSignature").Value;
```

In either case, you can then iterate using `foreach` - `encodedSignatures` will just be an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Thank You Sir!I am honored to receive an answer from Jon Skeet!